If else condition for PromQL
I am trying to write a promql query to achieve the following
Output total number of times that my_metric was < 1 grouped by namespace and for all other namespaces where there are no series of my_metric < 1 output 0
eg: For the following input
my_metric{namespace="a", proxy="api_backend"} 0
my_metric{namespace="a", proxy="api_backend_1"} 0
my_metric{namespace="a", proxy="api_backend_2"} 1
my_metric{namespace="b", proxy="api_backend"} 1
my_metric{namespace="b", proxy="api_backend_1"} 1
my_metric{namespace="c", proxy="api_backend"} 1

My ideal output is something like following
{namespace="a"} 2
{namespace="b"} 0
{namespace="c"} 0

I tried the following rule.
sum by (namespace) (count(my_metric < 1) by (namespace))

Here i get the output only for namespace a. But i would like a 0 for all other namespace. I also tried adding an
or on(namespace) vector(0) but as thats a vector it doesnt give me per namespace. Any pointers?

or group by(namespace) (my_metric*0)

Also, you don't need sum by (namespace)
